# Counting letters / characters in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I searched online and looked at the API Docs on how to count characters, and I'm currently using this: `$('.test').val().length;`

However, it's not working at all.

My div looks like this: `<div class="test">Count These Letters</div>`

I expect `$('.test').val().length;` to return `19`, but instead its returning `1`... am I using the wrong function?

Comment: Divs do not have a **value** but rather text or html as their content

Comment: val() should be used for inputs and text areas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For text, you'll need `.text()`, like this:

```
 $('.test').text().length
```

Comment: oh my god I feel so downright stupid right now. (I'll go kick myself for the remaining time I have till I can except your answer)

Comment: Happens to the best of us ;)